# Netbeans doesn't autocomplete properties of var of nested <ui:repeat>

Tags: jsf, netbeans, el, code-completion, uirepeat

Let me say I have a Book Library with a list of Book. A Book has a List of Page. Page has a list of Line.

In JSF, i'm trying to display all the lines, now I'm using `<h:dataTable>` or `<ui:repeat>` to iterate through the lists. When I'm on second level of hierarchy which is page, instead of showing the properties of page as lines, netbeans only show the properties of book again as available properties

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bookLibrary.books}" var="book">
    <ui:repeat value="#{book.pages}" var="page">
        <ui:repeat value="#{page.???}" var="line">
        </ui:repeat>
    </ui:repeat> </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: I don't see anything PrimeFaces in here. And your application, does it work if you type a field manually instead of relying on code completion?

Comment: Yes, I now found out that it works if I add the field manually. Its the code completion that's leading me to believe my code is wrong

Comment: I also have the very same issue. Sadly no solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I now found out that it works if I add the field manually. Its the code completion that's leading me to believe my code is wrong